# Can I use Google Fonts to design my own logotype?

Tags: fonts, logo, font-licensing

I am a digital marketing freelancer and I am starting to design my own logo. I would like to use two different fonts available onGoogle Fonts: "Poiret One" and "Syncopate". Therefore, I want to know if I am allowed to use them as a professional resource for my own professional career, or should I buy them instead?

Answer (score 1):

Its opensource. Hence you can use it. For detailed FAQs
https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq